# How do I fix this installation problem with multicore Solr on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: solr, ubuntu-10.04

**EDIT**

I've written up a quick howto on getting multicore going: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/solr-ubuntu-revisited/

Following instructions from the two sites below, I've installed [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) 6 and [Solr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr) 1.4.

- http://gist.github.com/204638
- https://wiki.fourkitchens.com/display/TECH/Solr+1.4+on+Ubuntu+9.10+and+CentOS+5

I have successfully got it up and running on a server running 9.04 with multicore support, but on the 10.04 I can't seem to get it to work.

I am able to reach localhost:xxxx/solr/ on the 10.04 box and see a single link to the Solr Admin, but following the link takes me to a 404 page with the following output:

```
/solr/admin/
HTTP Status 404 - missing core name in path
The requested resource (missing core name in path) is not available
```

I am also unable to access /solr/site1/ as I would except - it similarly returns a 404.

```
  <!-- from /var/solr/solr.xml, site dirs exist -->
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="site1" instanceDir="site1" />
    <core name="site2" instanceDir="site2" />
  </cores>

  <!-- from /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml -->
  <Context docBase="/var/solr/solr.war" debug="0" privileged="true" allowLinking="true" crossContext="true">  
      <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/var/solr" override="true" />
  </Context>
```

Comment: Bah! Configuration fail. Got it fixed.

Comment: I've got a blog post detailing how to do this step-by-step: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/solr-ubuntu-revisited/

Answer (score 4):

For those coming here via Google:

I had this same problem, which I eventually tracked down to permissions on the solr.home directory (the cores didn't exists as it couldn't create directories for them). Check the latest catalina log file in /var/log/tomcat6/ for any issues.

Comment: could you paste how the permissions issue is reported in the logs? For me I see: Mar 31, 2011 12:48:05 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: 
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context

Comment: Sorry, this was last year, so I don't have the logs anymore! As I recall it was obviously a permissions issue from the logs.

Comment: Thanks fixed it for me. Error reported had to do with a folder that couldn't be created, giving permission to the tomcat6 user fixed it for me.

Comment: Here are detailed instructions on how I got this fixed http://charlesleifer.com/blog/solr-ubuntu-revisited/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the link in `http://localhost:xxxx/solr/` is wrong, but the admin URL for site1 is `http://localhost:xxx/solr/site1/admin/` (notice the slash at the end, it's required, otherwise you'll get a 404).

A query in the site1 core would look like this: `http://localhost:xxxx/solr/site1/select/?q=solr&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on`

`http://localhost:xxx/solr/site1/` **is** a 404, that is the correct response.

Comment: Yeah, it's quite mysterious.  It's acting from the /solr/ url like there's no multiple cores, but when I try to reach the /admin/ url or /solr/<core name>/admin/ I get a 404.  I also am unable to hit it with a query.  I've tried:

* apt-get install solr-tomcat
* apt-get install tomcat6 and manually install solr
* manually install both

To no avail :(

Feel like it must be a misconfiguration of settings, but not sure where.  Also to reiterate, I have gotten things going fine on 9.04.